# Failed to save data in different rows using for loop in separate output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to save my calculation results in an output file (created using the **open** builtin function of python). My calculation uses a for loop in python and I want to save all my results in a separate output file. But unfortunately only the last value of the loop is saved in the output file. To make my question more clear below I'm sharing my code

```
Nlayers = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

e_bulk = -33.071

TE2 = [-64.883,-97.954,-131.026,-164.097,-197.169,-230.240,-263.312,-296.383,-329.455]

area = 13.635


for i in range(len(Nlayers)):

        n = Nlayers[i]

        e_slab = TE2[i]

        sigma1 = (e_slab - (n*e_bulk)) / (2)

        sigma2 = (e_slab - (n*e_bulk)) / (2*area)

        fd = open('surf_energy', 'w')

        print('{0:3d} {1:13.2f} {2:15.4f}'. format(n, sigma1,sigma2),file=fd)

        fd.close()
```

In my output file, the results(i.e.the value of sigma1 and sigma2) only for the last value of the loop is saved. But I want to save all results in the output file. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Nlayers = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
e_bulk = -33.071
TE2 = [-64.883,-97.954,-131.026,-164.097,-197.169,-230.240,-263.312,-296.383,-329.455]
area = 13.635

with open("surf_energy", 'w') as my_file: # this ensures resources will be released after the block's scope ;
    for i in range(len(Nlayers)):
        n = Nlayers[i]
        e_slab = TE2[i]
        sigma1 = (e_slab - (n*e_bulk)) / (2)
        sigma2 = (e_slab - (n*e_bulk)) / (2*area)
        print('{0:3d} {1:13.2f} {2:15.4f}'. format(n, sigma1, sigma2), file = my_file)


# cat surf_energy

  2          0.63          0.0462
  3          0.63          0.0462
  4          0.63          0.0461
  5          0.63          0.0461
  6          0.63          0.0461
  7          0.63          0.0461
  8          0.63          0.0461
  9          0.63          0.0461
 10          0.63          0.0460
```